# default value for method in cor()

Tags: r, function, correlation

I am using `GGally::ggscatmat` to generate plots of a correlation matrix. In the help file `?ggscatmat` it says that it calls `cor()` to compute the correlation. It does not list a default value. I started to look through `cor` to figure out the default value if method is not specified.

`?corr` lists `cor(x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))` so in order to interpret this I tried to understand the function `cor` itself:

```r
function (x, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", 
    "kendall", "spearman")) 
{
    na.method <- pmatch(use, c("all.obs", "complete.obs", 
        "pairwise.complete.obs", "everything", "na.or.complete"))
    if (is.na(na.method)) 
        stop("invalid 'use' argument")
    method <- match.arg(method)
    if (is.data.frame(y)) 
        y <- as.matrix(y)
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    if (!is.matrix(x) && is.null(y)) 
        stop("supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'")
    if (!(is.numeric(x) || is.logical(x))) 
        stop("'x' must be numeric")
    stopifnot(is.atomic(x))
    if (!is.null(y)) {
        if (!(is.numeric(y) || is.logical(y))) 
            stop("'y' must be numeric")
        stopifnot(is.atomic(y))
    }
    Rank <- function(u) {
        if (length(u) == 0L) 
            u
        else if (is.matrix(u)) {
            if (nrow(u) > 1L) 
                apply(u, 2L, rank, na.last = "keep")
            else row(u)
        }
        else rank(u, na.last = "keep")
    }
    if (method == "pearson") 
        .Call(C_cor, x, y, na.method, FALSE)
    else if (na.method %in% c(2L, 5L)) {
        if (is.null(y)) {
            .Call(C_cor, Rank(na.omit(x)), NULL, na.method, method == 
                "kendall")
        }
        else {
            nas <- attr(na.omit(cbind(x, y)), "na.action")
            dropNA <- function(x, nas) {
                if (length(nas)) {
                  if (is.matrix(x)) 
                    x[-nas, , drop = FALSE]
                  else x[-nas]
                }
                else x
            }
            .Call(C_cor, Rank(dropNA(x, nas)), Rank(dropNA(y, 
                nas)), na.method, method == "kendall")
        }
    }
    else if (na.method != 3L) {
        x <- Rank(x)
        if (!is.null(y)) 
            y <- Rank(y)
        .Call(C_cor, x, y, na.method, method == "kendall")
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(y)) {
            ncy <- ncx <- ncol(x)
            if (ncx == 0) 
                stop("'x' is empty")
            r <- matrix(0, nrow = ncx, ncol = ncy)
            for (i in seq_len(ncx)) {
                for (j in seq_len(i)) {
                  x2 <- x[, i]
                  y2 <- x[, j]
                  ok <- complete.cases(x2, y2)
                  x2 <- rank(x2[ok])
                  y2 <- rank(y2[ok])
                  r[i, j] <- if (any(ok)) 
                    .Call(C_cor, x2, y2, 1L, method == "kendall")
                  else NA
                }
            }
            r <- r + t(r) - diag(diag(r))
            rownames(r) <- colnames(x)
            colnames(r) <- colnames(x)
            r
        }
        else {
            if (length(x) == 0L || length(y) == 0L) 
                stop("both 'x' and 'y' must be non-empty")
            matrix_result <- is.matrix(x) || is.matrix(y)
            if (!is.matrix(x)) 
                x <- matrix(x, ncol = 1L)
            if (!is.matrix(y)) 
                y <- matrix(y, ncol = 1L)
            ncx <- ncol(x)
            ncy <- ncol(y)
            r <- matrix(0, nrow = ncx, ncol = ncy)
            for (i in seq_len(ncx)) {
                for (j in seq_len(ncy)) {
                  x2 <- x[, i]
                  y2 <- y[, j]
                  ok <- complete.cases(x2, y2)
                  x2 <- rank(x2[ok])
                  y2 <- rank(y2[ok])
                  r[i, j] <- if (any(ok)) 
                    .Call(C_cor, x2, y2, 1L, method == "kendall")
                  else NA
                }
            }
            rownames(r) <- colnames(x)
            colnames(r) <- colnames(y)
            if (matrix_result) 
                r
            else drop(r)
        }
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x0000024e4d4e22b0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Unfortunately, this is bringing me well beyond my ability to understand R. Could anybody explain how `cor` decides which method to apply if no method is specified?

Comment: `x <- rnorm(100); y <- rnorm(100); all.equal(cor(x, y), cor(x, y, method = "pearson"))`

Comment: Thank you for the example. It demonstrated the explanation by @DanY really well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: the first one listed, so "pearson"

---

A bit more info:

Line 8 specifies that `method <- match.arg(method)`.

This means that if the user specified `method="something"` then `"something"` is used.

However, if the user does not specify the `method` argument, then the default `method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman")` is used.  Ah, but then you will ask, which one? There's 3 listed there!  The answer to that is in how the `match.arg` function works.  See `?match.arg`, which states that the **first** element is used.

So in this case, if you call `cor(x, y)` without specifying the `method` argument, it's the same as `cor(x, y, method="pearson")`.  @missuse provides an example in the comments at the top, which I've copied here:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
all.equal( cor(x, y), 
           cor(x, y, method = "pearson") )
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for the explanation!